# Analysing core dump in linux sytem : error

Tags: linux, core-dump

We are using a private module to dump a corefile which uses the kernel utility `elf_core_dump` in `source/fs/binfmt_elf.c` file in kernel source 4.4.52.

Using this module we are getting a core of unlimited size. We use ARM gdb version "GNU gdb (Marvell GCC development 20170123-) 7.10.0.20150918-cvs" to debug a core file.

Using this tool, while opening core file we get the following error:

```
BFD: Warning: /tmp/filewXU3ip is truncated: expected core file size >= 1684632832, found: 102373296.
warning: Couldn't find general-purpose registers in core file.
warning: Couldn't find general-purpose registers in core file.
PC not available
```

Could someone please help us to get through this error? Do we need to do some other implementation for this in kernel apart from exporting necessary symbols?

Comment: would you include the output of `df -h`?

Comment: don't you have a ulimit set on core size? (ulimit -c ), maybe try with ulimit -c unlimited ?

Comment: Are you opening it as soon you generate core?

Comment: @tonioc ulimit -f also seems to affect core size.

Comment: yes the climit is set to unlimited using the option ulimit -c unlimited.

Comment: We extract the core file from the system send to another server in which the gdb is installed. This may take a while.

Comment: The size of the core file for a our process is 98 MB

Comment: It seems you forgot the `df -h`

Comment: [oxoinfra] : Owing to security reasons, I cannot share you the output of df -h. But I could tell you that there is enough place in the file system. Moreover, when we directly use the kernel module itself for core-dump, we get an unlimited core, which is readable and backtracable through arm-gdb.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you need to write it to filesystem with more space available.